# Simplest method for splitting CSV file based on column value

Tags: excel, csv, ms-office, openoffice-calc

I'm have a large list of every city in the world that I'm attempting to break down by country. Making this happen manually has been very tedious leading be to believe there is a better way to accomplish this. Which bring me to the follwing question.

What is the simplest/best way to split a CSV file into smaller CSV files based on similar values in one column?

I have seen this question answered a couple different ways assuming the person asking had experience in C++, which I do not. I have a very basic knowledge of Java, a bit more experience with Linux, and even more with Windows and Microsoft Office.

Any push in the right direction is helpful.

Thanks for taking the time to read this far.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are obviously many different ways you could accomplish this - if you're on Windows, [this snippet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70319/Splitting-CSV-file-based-on-content-in-one-line-us) provides a nice one-liner for PowerShell to split a csv file based on the values in a column:

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Group-Object -Property "department" | 
    Foreach-Object {$path=$_.name+".csv" ; $_.group | 
    Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation}
```

Replace `file.csv` with your csv file, and `"department"` with the column heading you want to break up files on.  It will write a new csv based on each unique value in the selected column.

If you've never used Powershell, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177003.aspx) is a decent introduction.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!   Very much appreciated.. Hopefully I can pay this forward in the very near future!

Answer (score 3):

On Linux or macOS you can use `awk` (where 2 is the column index to split on):

```
awk -F ',' '{print > ("cities-in-"$2".csv")}' cities.csv
```

## Input file

cities.csv:

```
1,london,uk
2,paris,france
3,bristol,uk
4,lyon,france
```

## Output files

cities-in-uk.csv:

```
1,london,uk
3,bristol,uk
```

city-data-paris.csv:

```
2,paris,france
4,lyon,france
```

Answer (score 1):

as you are doing it manually, I assume you don't necessarily need a code to achieve this. I am not familiar with Powershell, so can't comment on chrisb's answer. If you can get it working, it looks like it'll be simpler than my solution but in case you cannot, then you can try the following:

- Open your csv file in excel
- Insert a header row in the top row if not already there
- In the menu go to Data and click on filter. You'll see the funnel icon in all the headers.
- In the country header, select the country you want to get records of. You'll see the cities of only the selected country filtered.
- Copy the filtered columns in another excel sheet and save as a CSV file.
- Repeat the process for all countries.

If you want to automate it further then probably you'll have to go for some coding.